# PostgreSQL management on Ubuntu

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql

I'm looking for database management tool for PostgreSQL to host on Ruby. It would be nice to see and manage whole database and data on my Ubuntu VPS.

Is there any tools for this?

Maybe there is something similar like phpMyAdmin? Maybe as gem for Rails?

Thanks!

Comment: Rails specific, but a lot of people use [Active Admin](http://www.activeadmin.info).

Comment: That's use-case specific as well as rails-specific

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Squirrel](http://squirrel-sql.sf.net) is what I use to manage any JDBC-compatible database from my client PC. Both remote and local instances are supported. Alternatively, the postgres command-line application works fine for queries.

Comment: Thanks! You alse gave me idea to use pgAdmin remotely - it works perfect!